# How to upload a folder

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, upload

when I was writing the code, I encountered a headache that caused me to need to upload a folder. My front-end partner did give me a folder, but I couldn't get the name of the folder, so I couldn't create a folder.

```java
@PostMapping("/upload")
    @Operation(summary = "upload file")
    public Result upload(@RequestPart MultipartFile[] files, Folder folder){
        log.info("upload-->{}","start");
        log.info("Upload root path-->{}",folder.getRootPath());
        for (MultipartFile file : files) {
            String filename = file.getOriginalFilename();
            log.debug("File name-->{}",filename);
            String type = file.getContentType();
            log.debug("File type-->{}",type);
            log.debug("File Name-->{}",file.getOriginalFilename());
        }
        log.info("upload-->{}","en");
        return new Result().result200("end",request.getRequestURI());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The folder name should be saved in the fulle filename like `a_folder/a_file.txt`.

[image]

Comment: Hello, the problem I have is because `Spring` upload files need to use `MultipartFile` to upload, he has no sign of the superior directory, so I can't create the folder

Comment: if you cannot find the folder name in the filename which is queried by `file.getOriginalFilename()`, this may be caused by the frontend that they have not passed the full filepath.

Comment: I uploaded a image about the usage of the function `getOriginalFilename`.

Comment: So,  this is your backend's problem, it is depended by the client or the frontend, or you cannot get the folder name.

Comment: My front-end friends can only use `chrome` to get the relative path of the folder, but not the absolute path.

Comment: Yeah, according to the explanation of the func `getOriginalFilename`, the relative path should also be got

Answer (score 0):

If the folder name is passed to this handler method through a POST you need to add a @RequestParam on the Folder parameter like so

```
public Result upload(@RequestPart MultipartFile[] files, @RequestParam Folder folder)
```

Comment: No, I want to transfer parameters and files, but because `swagger` is not able to display the parameters, I chose this way.